# Annihilator as a subspace of $\mathcal L(V;W)$ (generalization of 3.106 of Linear Algebra Done Right)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V,W$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ and $U\subseteq V$ be a subspace of $V$. If we define a subspace of $\mathcal L(V;W)$, space of all linear operators between $V$ and $W$, by $$U^0=\{\phi \in \mathcal L(V;W):\phi(u)=0\textrm{ for all }u \in U\},$$ then can we say that $\dim U+\dim U^0=\dim V$ or we can say some another formulation like $\dim U+\dim U^0=\dim V. \dim W$?

If $W=\mathbb R$, then we can say the above formula. I was trying to prove it as it is in Axler's 'Linear Algebra Done Right' book (Theorem $3.106$)  but I can't prove it in general case. Actually I took one map $i':\mathcal L(V;W)\to U'$ and was trying to prove that null $i'=U^0$ and range $i'=U'.$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $i: U \to V$ is the injection of $U$ into $V$, then $U^0$ is the null space of the restriction map
\begin{align}
R:\ & {\cal L}(V, W)\to {\cal L}(U, W)\cr
& \phi\mapsto \phi \circ i
\end{align}
This map is onto, hence by the rank-nullity theorem
\begin{equation}
\dim {\cal L}(U, W) + \dim U^0 = \dim {\cal L}(V, W)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Note that $null \,i'$ is a subspace of $V'$. Thus each element of $null \,i'$ is a linear functional on $V$.
$\,$To show that $null \,i'= U^0$, suppose $\varphi\in null \,i'$. Then
$$0=(i'(\varphi))(u)=(\varphi \circ i)(u)=\varphi (i(u))=\varphi (u)$$
Thus $\varphi \in U^0$. Namely $null \,i'\subset U^0$. Clearly the inclusion in the other direction holds (because if $\varphi \in U^0$, by definitions of $i'$, inclusion map and of course (3.102), we have that $\varphi \in  null \,i'$). Hence  $null \,i'= U^0$.